# How to click on a button with only classname? Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Im having trouble to let Selenium click on a button for me.The button is:

```
<button data-v-4c4862d1="" data-v-149d3c0b="" class="btn btn-success">
          Activate
        </button>
```

I tried the following things :

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-success').click()
```

as well as ;

```
activate_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-success')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(activate_button).click(activate_button).perform()
```

Both delivered no result unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-success').click()` ?

Comment: Yea same result. Is there not a way to click using the data values inside the button tag?

Answer (score 0):

The line `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-success')` only finds the element but does not "click".

Try this:

```
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn btn-success')
element_to_click.click()
```

Comment: Oh sorry i missed that there was a .click behind it

Also tried it result is the same : DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/osman/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver') Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-success"} (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.110)